# Angular HTTP Client Interceptor not working when returning custom Observable

Tags: angular, angular-universal

***FYI This issue is related to Angular Universal***

I am currently trying to create an HttpClient Interceptor that caches GET requests and returns the cached response as an observable.

I tried following the guide set by Angular interceptors here https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/aio/content/guide/http.md but I can't seem to get it working, when I return an Observable other than next.handle() the subscription just doesn't get triggered.

Here is a plunker demoing it not working. https://plnkr.co/edit/QzVpuIoj3ZFXgHm7hVW2?p=preview

Example interceptor:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  // if this is cached, return the cached response.
  return Observable.of({body: 'Test'});

  return next
    .handle(customReq)
    .do((ev: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (ev instanceof HttpResponse) {
        // Cache this response
      }
    });
 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My goal ultimately is to get this working with NG Universal's Transfer Module. If I fix this problem in the interceptor then I should have that all working and ready to go.

***Edit:*** My assumption was wrong. The Angular HttpClient Interceptor Caching example works absolutely fine, it must be Angular Universal that is failing for me. (I updated Plunker with the working example from Angular, to prove that it's working for that case).

Here is my interceptor I use for Angular Universal.

```
constructor(private state: TransferState) {}

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (request.method !== "GET") {
        return next.handle(request);
    }

    const STATE_KEY = makeStateKey(request.urlWithParams);
    const cachedResponse = this.state.get(STATE_KEY, null);

    if (cachedResponse) {
        return Observable.of(cachedResponse);
    }

    return next.handle(request).do(event => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            this.state.set(STATE_KEY, event.clone());
        }
    });
}
```

Maybe it's some sort of timing issue with the TransferState service, I am not sure.

Comment: Your example interceptor contains unreachable code. Please give a proper [mcve].

Comment: Well, you're not returning a cached response. You're returning  an objet with a body attribute. It's supposed to be an HttpEvent. Wh don't you return a cached response?

Comment: I updated the description of this post.

Sorry about wasting your guys time with a bad question. It's hard to debug this problem in Angular Universal.

Answer (score 10):

I got it working. It makes sense but I can't believe it took me so long to realise the small fix. When I am returning the Observable of cachedResponse, I need to create a new HttpResponse object, since it's a class not just an interface. Thus like this:

```
return Observable.of(new HttpResponse<any>(cachedResponse));
```

*Updated code snippet for new version of RXJS:*

```
return of(new HttpResponse<any>(cachedResponse));
```

Comment: Thanks, had the same problem. Just a little fix (possibly because of the changes in the current version of Angular): Observable does not contain of so need to do `import { of } from "rxjs/observable/of";` and then (in case cache contains body string): return of(new HttpResponse<any>({ body: cachedResponse }));`